# Is making a question "politically correct" part of copy editing?

Tags: discussion, edits

I edited this question on StackOverflow: [Keytool facebook app for android not working on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555175/keytool-facebook-app-for-android-not-working-on-device)

And I'm not sure if I crossed a line or not.

The original post said:

> please, anyone have a tutorial for
>   very dummie people to solve this?

Which I changed to:

> Please, does anyone have a tutorial
>   for beginners to
>   help me solve this?

I don't think I changed the intended meaning of the question - but, perhaps, I changed the meaning slightly - based on my assumptions regarding the OP's intent.

Seems OK to me... but I'm unsure about these types of changes in general.

Thanks.

Comment: That change looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for taking a whack at that question -- I tried a dozen re-writings and then gave up when my pizza finished baking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making sure posts have decent grammar is part of copy editing, and I'd support that change on those grounds alone.

Even if it started out as "Does anyone have a tutorial for dummies?" though, I think it's still a good improvement. It's good to have standards. Saying posts should be "professional" might be overstating things a bit, but they should at least seem like they were written by adults. And I loathe those "... for Dummies" books.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. (RE: "And I loathe those 'for Dummies' books." - LOL... me too.)

Comment: No, expecting posts to be "professional" is not at all overstating things.